# Как узнать время выполнения каждой функции в PHP скрипте.

Tags: php

Здравствуйте, коллеги.

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как определить время выполнения каждой из функций в PHP скрипте, да и вообще, чем занят PHP во время выполнения? Слышал про профайлеры, в частности про xdebug, но, насколько я понял, он должен работать в паре с какой-то IDE (аля NetBeans), а мне бы хотелось все на одном linux сервере тестировать. Возможно, существует какой-то плагин или библиотека для решения данного вопроса?

Благодарю.

С уважением.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Смотрите в сторону xhprof.

[Профилирование и отладка php-приложений с помощью xhprof & FirePHP](http://habrahabr.ru/post/145895/)

Comment: Благодарю за помощь. То, что надо. Инструкция по установке https://stojg.se/blog/2011-08-27-install-xhprof-for-php5-on-centos-ubuntu-and-debian